# Docker creates same proxy twice

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My docker is suddenly trying to create 2 proxies on the same port and essentially erroring out itself. This same container works fine on my friend's PC and it used to work fine for me as well but now I'm getting this-

> Creating psty-main_psty_main_1 ... done
>
> Creating psty-main_proxy_1    ...
>
> Creating psty-main_proxy_1      ... error
>
> ERROR: for psty-main_proxy_1  Cannot start service proxy: driver
>
> failed programming external connectivity on endpoint psty-main_proxy_1
>
> (58b7942fc459b490cd0fc3e3b81b42b182d995a8e7cb095c3b7 94df55d8adac4):
>
> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use
>
> ERROR: for proxy  Cannot start service proxy: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint psty-main_proxy_1
>
> (58b7942fc459b490cd0fc3e3b81b42b182d995a8e7cb095c3b794df55d8adac 4):
>
> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address
>   already in use
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  psty_main:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - "./app:/usr/src/app"
    environment:
      - FLASK_DEBUG=0
      - PYTHONBUFFERED=1
  proxy:
    build: ./nginx
    links:
      - psty_main:psty_main
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    environment:
      - PYTHONBUFFERED=1
```

Before I use `docker-compose up --build` and get that error, this is what the environment looks like;

`docker ps` returns

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

It's empty

`docker network ls` returns

```
 NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE

 a7dfa1d12898        bridge              bridge              local

 bdd53f5074e5        host                host                local

 11afefbc2023        none                null                local
```

`docker container ls -a` returns

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

Also empty

**Note**: I did notice that the web service is created perfectly fine, even after docker throws this error, I can simply go to 127.0.0.1:5000 and it'll show me perfectly working website. It's just that I no longer have access to the console that logs the server's status due to the error.

Comment: You have two containers that are both trying to bind port 5000, one only on the loopback interface and one on all interfaces; if you delete the `ports:` under `psty_main` does it work better?  Are you running a copy of the service outside of Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze I ran `netstat -a` to see if there were any services on that port, nothing. I don't think I'm running a service. It does seem however, removing `ports:` under `psty_main` works. But why? This same `docker-compose` worked fine before